# Bheem v/s Duryodhan Mace Battle in Mahabharata

Tags: mahabharata, bhagavad-gita

I would like to know the following.

In between the mace battle between the mighty Bheem and Duryodhan, had the battle continued for many many days further, who would have been victorious?

Both Bheem and Duryodhan were disciples of Balram.

Comment: It doesn't matter how many days the battle continued, the defeat of Duryodhana in this battle was inevitable, for the one who was supporting Bhīma was Kṛṣṇa, and wherever there's Kṛṣṇa, there's jaya(*yataḥ kṛṣṇas tato jayaḥ*). Wherever there's Kṛṣṇa, there's dharma, and where there's dharma, there's jaya. (*yataḥ kṛṣṇastato dharmo yato dharmastato jayaḥ*)